# Should link to other SO sites when searches don't pan out

Tags: feature-request, search

When you do a search and come up with nothing, there are a bunch of search suggestions, such as surrounding your search in quotes or using Google.

You should also include links to search the other affialiated sites. So if I was to search for 'hot chipset action' and it was to return nothing (which, unsurprisingly, it does) I would get something like this:

- Search [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=hot+chipset+action) for **hot chipset action**
- Search [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=hot+chipset+action) for **hot chipset action**

Answer (score 6):

Rather than providing alternative search links, why not just do the searches?

"No results were found on StackOverflow, but your search matched the following questions on ServerFault and SuperUser..."

Each site would have to be configured with a set of *relevant* sibling sites (so that cookingoverflow.com didn't search SO, for example).

Comment: I hope no-one searches for recursion

Answer (score 2):

Why do we even need different sites for different types of questions?  Isn't that what tagging is supposed to solve?

Comment: As there are already 4 SO-engine sites, I think the ship that complaint should have been on has well and truly sailed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting idea, but I wonder how large the (useful) crossover is... most of the things I'd be interested in would be pretty specific to SO.

Comment: Things like the database grey area raised recently, I guess.