# Searching more than one of the stackoverflow sites

Tags: support, search

Is there a way of searching on more than one of the stackoverflow sites.  I asked a question on SU and was pointed to an answer on SO.  I had tried looking on Superuser first!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13462/add-search-other-sites-to-search-results-page and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/should-link-to-other-so-sites-when-searches-dont-pan-out

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/how-do-i-google-the-whole-trilogy-of-stackoverflow-sites

Comment: And here's another: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites

Comment: Not sure about @json suggestion. That refers to "Google" rather than "search".  They are not synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there shouldn't be a real need for this, due to the lines drawn between the sites. If you answer was found on SO, your question probably belonged on SO.

Comment: **Many** questions are fine both on SU and SF. The only difference between the two is **the asker** ; if he paid for his computer then it's SU otherwise SF.

Comment: Not sure I totally agree with that.  There is a grey area.  "How do you define your own shortcuts in Outlook 2007" seems like obvious SU material, but it transpires that it had been asked on SO (I presume before SU existed). Anyway the google way looks like a workround

Answer (score 2):

This link lets you search all of the StackOverflow sites:

http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=018205968162215846785:ge5giybfqde

Answer (score 0):

Since good search is hard, it'd probably be better for you to consult the "experts" when searching. It's very easy to search StackOverflow or SuperUser specifically via Google using the following format in the search textbox:

```
keyword site:stackoverflow.com
```

The only bummer (I just found out) is that you can only search one site at a time. On the other hand, as Jon B said, each site really offers different types of questions, so you *shouldn't* get too many overlapping hits from one site to another (unless your search is too broad).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dupe, but I can't find it.

You can just use [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/).

[SOFU Google Search](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=000024428840691983588:0q8yb1lark8) (just made, seems like it's available for everyone.)